# How to replace text in output from format-list in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I run the following command to get a very basic audit of file permissions in PS:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory E:\*,E:\*\*,E:\*\*\* | 
Get-Acl | Format-list Path,AccessToString | 
Out-File -Filepath c:\myfile.txt
```

The output of `Format-List` contains info in the path I want to strip out, namely `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::`

But if I add `{$_ -replace "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::",""}` before the output file pipe I get errors.

Is there a way to parse out this data through a piped output, or do I have to create a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Convert-Path`

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\*,C:\*\*,C:\*\*\* | 
Get-Acl | Format-list @{N="Path";E={Convert-Path $_.Path}},AccessToString | 
Out-File -Filepath c:\myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You could inline replace the contents of Format-List using a calculated property like this

```
@{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")}}
```

Your command then becomes

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\* |
Get-acl |
Format-List @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")}}, accesstostring |
Out-File -filepath c:\myfile.txt
```

Comment: That worked great, can you give me a breakdown? This will be really useful in other situations but I think Avshalom's answer was more concise. This was very helpful, though, thanks!